# SQL Server 2012 Connecting to MS Access 2003

Tags: microsoft-access, sql-server

SQL Server 2012 - Access 32-bit 2003 - I can import the database, I don't understand why I can't link to it.  SQL 2012 may have changed the connection string or something.

I just installed SQL Server 2012 to test differences and make sure it is ok for my Work. I may not be a pro at SQL, but I don't see how to add a Link to Jet database on my server. I have imported Jet Databases, but when going thru the GUI to Link a JET Database I see no Provider for JET. I am running Access 2003 (I don't like the 2008+ GUI)

I searched an found nothing similar to my issue; at least nothing I understood. Nothing mentioned how to add Jet db Provider.

I ran a connection string to the Jet Database thru QA:

```
sp_addlinkedserver 'USGEScrub', 'Access', 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',  
'D:\Lead$\SupList\USGEScrub.mdb'
```

The connection string works till I try to access the data and then I get this the error and of course if I click the links nothing shows up:

> #### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlinkProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476
>
> #### ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. 
>    Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked 
>    server "USGEScrub". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7302)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlinkProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=11.00.2100&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=7302&LinkId=20476

Answer (score 0):

looks like it might be to do with the drivers.
Here is Microsoft's take on the issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2555855